# Получение значения инпутов в массив

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток.
Представим, что есть 3 текстовых инпута, в которые вводят какие-то значения (*не обязательно во все, а допустим только в 2 из 3х*), как эти значения закинуть в массив для дальнейшего использования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можем просто использовать [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
Потом для каждый элемент записываем в массив, если он не пустой.

```js
// Нужный нам массив
var a = [];

// Для удобства
$('#add').on('click', function() {

  // Для каждого поля запоминаем значение введённое пользователем
  $('.input').each(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();   // Получаем значение из текстового поля
    if (input != '') {           // Если не пустая строка
      a.push(input);             // Добавляем значение в конец массива
    }
  });
  console.log('Added');
  
});

// При нажатии на вторую кнопку...
$('#show').on('click', function() {

  // Вывод массива. Для каждого элемента выводить...
  a.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + item);
  });

});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="input"> 
<input type="text" class="input"> 
<input type="text" class="input"> 

<button id="add">Добавить в массив</button>
<button id="show">Показать массив</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам больше, это прям то, что нужно)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, всегда пожалуйста :)